# Add new number and comma at the end of value

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a number like `1234`. I want to add new number `00` and `,` and `€` at the end. Now number will be like `1234,00€` I can not figure out.

Comment: You can do this with plain vanilla JS.

Comment: try `'1234€'.replace(/(€)$/, ',00$1')`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript)

Comment: try `alert('1234€'.replace(/(€)$/, ',00$1'));`

Comment: Try this: `var s = 1234 + '00,€'`

Comment: Calling `string.replace()` on a number won't work.

Comment: jahroy@ Thank you vaery much. It work's for me.

Answer (score 3):

That will work for you:

```
var value = '1234';
var formatted = value.replace(/(\d+)/, '$1,00€');
```

But, I strongly recommend you to read the answers in this question: [How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript)

---

**Update** as @jared said, you can just concatenate the text: `,00€` to your number to *just* get the desired results.

Comment: @Subir, I doubled checked it, and I updated it. Check it now.

Comment: What's wrong with `var s = 1234 + '00,€'`? There's no need for regex, **or** `string.replace()` **and** there's no need to convert the original value to a string.  Note that the OP is using a number (not a string). Trying to invoke `string.replace()` on a number will cause an error.

Comment: You are right @jahroy